# Python BeautifulSoup doesn't works on URL

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm happy to join Stack Overflow :) First time i don't find an answer at my problem :)

I would like to scrap "meta description" on url list (in a SQL data base).

When I started my script, it gets "killed" without any error. It gets killed reading the 11th URL.

I made some tests, and I identified an URL : "http://www.les-calories.com/famille-4.html"

So i made this test, reducing my code at minimum :

```
# encoding=utf8 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
html = urllib.urlopen(" http://www.les-calories.com/famille-4.html").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

And this code gets "killed" by the shell.

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMdGI.jpg)

I don't understand why...

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Hi @metalups, don't you have any error codes?

Comment: No error, just "killed" on the shell (see screen above)

Comment: I don't see anything on my logs : /var/log/kern.log is empty

Comment: It worked fine on my machine .. python 2.7, Ubuntu.. in python interactive interpreter.  What is the 'kill' business about?

Comment: I d'ont understand, maybe as said "Games Brainiac" it is because of the length on html ?
Script stop with this only message : "killed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that you've not specified the parser in which case do the following.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

However, I think what is more likely is that there was just too much information in the HTML page. What I'd do is use the python-requests package, and in the GET request, I'd set `stream` to `True`. Like so:

```
>>> import requests
>>> resp = requests.get("http://www.les-calories.com/famille-4.html", stream=True)
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "html.parser")
>>> soup.find("a")
<a href="http://www.fitadium.com/79-seche-et-definition-musculaire" target="_blank"><img border="0" height="60px" src="h
ttp://www.les-calories.com/images/234x60_pack-minceur-brule-graisses.gif" width="234px"/></a>
```

Comment: Hello,
Thank you, but i have found this tip on Stack Overflow, and it doesn't work for me :
the code above, addind "html.parser", is not killed, but is veeeeery long to end.
Also, if I use "html.parser", when my script get this URL, i have the "killed" message (after a long time). Does the code above works for you ? With this URL ?

Comment: Could you be more specific and give a full traceback then?

Comment: Yes, the code works for me. I used the website you posted in your question. Seems to be fine for me. The issue is that the website is very large.

Comment: Hello,
I have thie type error with your code :
TypeError: expected string or buffer
Following the advices from Stack Overflow, i have tried 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(str(resp.text), "html.parser") but it doesn't work.

Comment: This doens'nt works with your code 


`# encoding=utf8` 
`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup import requests`
`resp = requests.get("http://www.fatsecret.fr/Diary.aspx?pa=fjrd&rid=4832461", stream=True)`
`soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "html.parser")`

Comment: You have to be more specific than "it doesn't work".

Comment: When i launch my script, i wait a while and i have juste a message "killed".